# How do I set up speakers in series and/or parallel for a minimum 4 ohm load on the amplifier?

Tags: audio, impedance, speakers

I need to connect 4 speakers to 1 output of a power amplifier.

All speakers are identical (100 watts @ 8ohms) and the minimum load permissible on the amp is 4 ohms.

They can be connected in series and/or parallel, but the final load on the amp needs to be a minimum of 4 ohms.

What would be the final load?

What would be the final wattage?

[image: Connect 4 x 8 ohm speakers in series and/or parallel]

Comment: What wattage can the amplifier provide? You can connect as many speakers as you can but final wattage totally depends on the power amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect two speakers in series (making two sets), then connect the two sets in parallel, that would result in 8Ohm total impedance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffvYl0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is this correct then?

http://i.imgur.com/HAZyktH.png

Comment: And you would get half the maximum power of the amplifier. Power is V²/R and since you've doubled the R value from the minimum the amp can handle your power will be halved. So, you could achieve the same _power_ with just two speakers in parallel. The advantage with four is they'd be running cooler, maybe less distortion and, if it's a help, better room coverage.